# Bigcommerce Stencil server response time is much higher than blueprint themes, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigcommerce, pagespeed

I have recently upgraded my client's site from the Bigcommerce Classic Next blueprint-based theme to the new Bigcommerce Stencil framework. The new theme is based on Bigcommerce's Cornerstone theme, with some layout changes and functionality enhancements.

A big reason we decided to make the switch was to give us more control over the theme files so that we can optimize the load time as much as possible. I was assuming that modern best practices such as bundling/minifying javascript, switching to sass, using npm packages, etc. would give us a significant load time boost over the old theme framework.

Unfortunately, page load time according to Google Analytics, Pingdom and New Relic is roughly the same, if not higher. The main offender from Stencil is the server response time (please see attached image showing before and after stencil theme install). I believe this is Stencil's node.js server code and has nothing to do with my theme files, correct?

**Is there any way for me to reduce this load time?**

[image: 1]

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?